# How to use Distinct top in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, syntax-error

I'm trying to solve the 2nd highest salary

```
Select distinct top 2 salary from employee;
```

My code shows a syntax error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '2 salary from employee' at line 1

I'm using MySQL Workbench.

Comment: This isn't MySQL dialect

Answer (score 1):

You can order the query and use a `limit` clause:

```sql
SELECT   DISTINCT salary
FROM     employees
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT    2
```

Comment: This makes specific assumptions about the the data set.

Comment: @Ivan          It is likely Mureinik's answer will be reasonable for your request.  Unless Strawberry wants to share additional details about why it would not be reasonable in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik, I thought MySQL allows TOP function as I followed along with the Youtube tutorial but your code is much easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second highest salary in MySQL, you want `limit` and `offset`:

```
Select distinct salary
from employee
order by salary desc
limit 1 offset 1;
```